# Unhandled match case Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel

So, I have a controller in Laravel that handles URLs.

```
    public function showEvents($course)
    {
        // function for the /events/{$course} pages
        try {
            [$view, $id] = match ($course) {
                // URL Request from ($course) then the set the $view and $id
                'lorem' => ['pages.course.lorem', '2'],
                'impsum' => ['pages.course.impsum', '3'],
                'impsumlorem' => ['pages.course.impsumlorem', '4'],
                'loremimpsum' => ['pages.course.loremimpsum', '5'],
                'loremloremimpsum' => ['pages.course.loremloremimpsum', '6'],
                'impsumimpsomlorem' => ['pages.course.impsumimpsumlorem', '7'],
                'looreem' => ['pages.course.looreem', '8'],
            };


            return view($view, [
                'events' => Events::query()
                    ->orderBy('title')
                    ->orderBy('start')
                    ->where('category', $id)
                    ->where('start', '>', now())
                    ->get()

            ]);
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            // if no match was found return 404 error
            abort(404);
        }
    }
```

So If I have for example this URL:
`/events/289-loremimpsum-level2`

and if this URL is not found in my DB it throws an `Unhandled Match Case`

I cannot do a `default` because this would break the event page that the users get shown.

Users should get redirected with a error message to route name `all-events` In my example above it does not even abort with a 404 error. I have no idea how to fix this issue for our users.

Comment: I woulds suggest adding a default anyway, then between your match and return, check for that default value. If it hits that default value, then abort

Comment: `default => redirect()->route('all-events')`

Comment: Also: `default => redirect()->route('all-events')->with('error', 'Event not found.')`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/redirects

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thank you for these info. That really helped me with refactoring the code! Have a great day! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can throw exception in default like this and then catch the error:

```
[$view, $id] = match ($course) {
            // URL Request from ($course) then the set the $view and $id
            'lorem' => ['pages.course.lorem', '2'],
            'impsum' => ['pages.course.impsum', '3'],
            'impsumlorem' => ['pages.course.impsumlorem', '4'],
            'loremimpsum' => ['pages.course.loremimpsum', '5'],
            'loremloremimpsum' => ['pages.course.loremloremimpsum', '6'],
            'impsumimpsomlorem' => ['pages.course.impsumimpsumlorem', '7'],
            'looreem' => ['pages.course.looreem', '8'],
            default => throw new \Exception('Not Found'),
        };
```

Comment: This is the best solution, I refactored that code and implemented a try and catch with these exceptions and now redirect to the route "all-events". Thank you for your help!